# using ngModelChange it does not change date when user selects the date first time using date picker

Tags: javascript, angular

I am using two date picker From date and To date , actually what i want is that when user picks a date (From date picker) and that date is greater then the value of (To date picker) its should then assign the (From date picker) value to (To date picker) as well and vice versa.

I am using the following code but its not working properly

Component File

```
if (callFrom == 'from' && claimCharge.Dos_From) {
  if (this.getLengthOfYear(claimCharge.Dos_To)) {
    if (this.checkIfTodayDate(claimCharge.Dos_To)) {
      if (this.getLengthOfDate(claimCharge.Dos_From)) {
        .Dos_To = claimCharge.Dos_From;
      }
    }
  }
}


if (callFrom == 'from' && claimCharge.Dos_From) {
  if (claimCharge.Dos_From >= claimCharge.Dos_To) {
    if (this.getLengthOfYear(claimCharge.Dos_From)) {
      if (claimCharge.Dos_To.toString() != new Date(new Date().setHours(0, 0, 0, 0)).toString() as any) {
        claimCharge.Dos_To = claimCharge.Dos_From;
      }
    }
  }
}
```

HTML :

```
<datetime  [attr.id]="'txtProcedureDOSTo_'+ndx" [timepicker]="false" [datepicker]="datepickerOpts" (ngModelChange)="methodFromAndToCheck(p,'to')" [(ngModel)]="p.Dos_To" ></datetime>
<datetime  [attr.id]="'txtProcedureDOSFrom_'+ndx" [timepicker]="false" [datepicker]="datepickerOpts" (ngModelChange)="methodFromAndToCheck(p,'from')" [(ngModel)]="p.Dos_From"></datetime>
```

Comment: Does not it fire the onChange event? What is the exact the problem. Please describe it correctly.

Answer (score 0):

Hopefully I have understood you correctly, that is my solution:

HTML:

```
 <input placeholder="From" [(ngModel)]="from" type="date" (change)="onChange('from')">

 <input placeholder="To" [(ngModel)]="to" type="date" (change)="onChange('to')">
```

TS Component:

```
import {Component, OnInit} from '@angular/core'

@Component({
  selector: 'date',
  templateUrl: './date.component.html',
  styleUrls: ['./date.component.css']
})
export class DateComponent implements OnInit {
  from: string;
  to: string;

  ngOnInit(){
    // get current date to set the starting values for inputs
    // d is a type of Date()

    let d = new Date();

    // d.toISOString() returns date in format YYYY-MM-DDTHH:mm:ss.sssZ
    // since input of "date" type uses YYYY-MM-DD format
    // we take first 10 characters with .slice(0,10)

    this.from = d.toISOString().slice(0,10);
    this.to = d.toISOString().slice(0,10);
  }

  onChange(input: string){
    if (input === 'from') {
      // if Date from input "to" is less than from input "from"
      // value of the input "to" is equal to value of the input "from"

      this.to = new Date(this.to) < new Date(this.from) ? this.to = this.from : this.to;

    } else {

      // if Date from input "to" is less than from input "from"
      // value of the input "from" is equal to value of the input "to"

      this.from = new Date(this.to) < new Date(this.from) ? this.from = this.to : this.from;

    }
  }
}
```

Let me know if it worked for you as well.

Comment: ` if (callFrom == 'to' && claimCharge.Dos_To) {
            alert(claimCharge.Dos_To);
            if (claimCharge.Dos_To <= claimCharge.Dos_From) {
                if (claimCharge.Dos_To.toString() != new Date(new Date().setHours(0, 0, 0, 0)).toString() as any) {
                    if (this.getLengthOfYear(claimCharge.Dos_To)) {
                        claimCharge.Dos_From = claimCharge.Dos_To;
                    }
                }
            }
        }`

Comment: The second condition this which i pasted above

Comment: This gives errror this.from = d.toISOString().slice(0,10); Error The supplied parameter donot match any signature of call type . I have this.from of type Date

Comment: d.toISOString().slice(0,10) - returns string. 
this.from should be string. Or try just to user d.toISOString().
I can say fo sure how to be here, because I do not know what format you date picker uses. If you will try my code with <input> tags, and define this.from as a string it will work

Comment: this.from is of type type Date

Comment: I added a comments to my code above to explain why I used .toISOString() and .slice(0,10).

but if this.from is of type Date just use:

let d = new Date();
d.setHours(0, 0, 0, 0);
this.from = d;

Comment: thnku Arttu for help it was helpful for me :)

Comment: Good luck with coding. P.S. Please rate the answer if you belive that it was helpful.